# Nesting Curly Braces in Liquid Template

Tags: liquid

For the following…

```
{{ meta['cover'] | fallback:'http://fallback.jpg' }}
```

How can I replace `http://fallback.jpg` with `{{ site.meta['cover_default'] }}` ?

`{{ meta['cover'] | fallback:'{{ site.meta['cover_default'] }}' }}` outputs `"/assets/filename.jpg' }}"`.

Notice the extra `}}` at the end. I have already tried to use capture and assign, both without luck. Is there a way to escape this so it outputs correctly?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to nest curly braces, just drop the quotation marks.

This example is specific to Siteleaf, but adding `.value` will ensure you are checking for the presence of the metadata’s `value`:

```
{{meta['cover'].value | fallback:site.meta['cover_default'].value}}
```